# Verbal strategy that requests action of someone without using a direct command

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to define the verbal strategy that requests action of someone without using a direct command—e.g., *Could you please open the door*?

Answer (score 6):

Steven Pinker calls it [off-record indirect speech acts](http://pinker.wjh.harvard.edu/articles/papers/Evolutionary%20social%20psychology%20of%20off-record%20indirect%20speech%20acts.pdf)...

> [off-the-record](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-record)
>   *the given or made in confidence and not for publication  comments (in contrast to **on the record**)*
>
> Indirect speech
>    the phenomenon in which a speaker says something he doesn’t literally mean, knowing that the hearer will interpret it as he intended.

Note that Pinker's definition of *indirect speech* as quoted there isn't the same as the more well-known [reported speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) one. But if you Google ["indirect speech act"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22indirect%20speech%20act%22&oq=%22indirect%20speech%20act%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.777&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it's obvious in that particular collocation Pinker's meaning is invariably what's meant.

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Politeness Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory) for _off-record_ terminology. There are several technical terms that fall within the scope of the question, but "indirect speech" is part of all of them.

Comment: @John: I knew I'd actually heard/seen Pinker talking about this a few years ago (next to you, he's my biggest linguistics hero! :). I specifically remembered him using the example of *"Could you pass the salt?"*, and sure enough, a Google search with judiciously-chosen terms turned up [this interview](http://bigthink.com/ideas/24077). I'd forgotten how eloquently he strips bare the way such devices define/alter/announce relationships between speakers - either more or less subtly, according to who those speakers are, and how "careful" they're being.

Comment: What does *off-record* have to do with it? Edit: I see the wikipedia article equates *off-record* speech with *indirect* speech, but your definition of off-record in the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with this meaning.

Comment: @user545424: What's not clear? I quoted Pinker's definition - which as John implies, is the one relevant to *speech acts* as under consideration here. I just mentioned that in some other contexts *indirect speech* is a synonym for *reported speech* or *indirect discourse* (probably not so much in more recent academic contexts, since grammarians and language teachers will largely have ceded that terminology to linguists).

Comment: I see the paper's title but can't find that definition for off-the-record anywhere in the paper; I don't see what "made in confidence and not for publication" has to do with it. I think you nailed the term, but I'm wondering why you have that particular definition in your answer.

Comment: @user545424: Sorry. I was talking about Pinker's definition of *indirect speech*. His usage of *off the record* is just a trivial extension of the more common context where, say, a politician speaks to reporters *off the record*, meaning they can't print his words; he can't be held to account for saying them. Pinker means much the same - for example, the speaker can't be criticised for openly saying something if he didn't say it *directly*. Maybe he didn't really mean whatever the hearer chose to interpret from his couched language.

Answer (score 2):

The term *[cajole](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/cajole)* is defined as

> to try to persuade someone to do something by saying things that please the person or make the person feel important

It is also [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cajole) as

> to obtain from someone by gentle persuasion

Answer (score 1):

Although the AHDEL doesn't license the word **request** in this usage

**re·quest**  (r-kwst)
tr.v. re·quest·ed, re·quest·ing, re·quests

1. To express a desire for; ask for.

... is as near as it gets ...

...Collins does:

**request** [rɪˈkwɛst]
vb (tr)
to express a desire for, esp politely; ask for or **demand** [bolding mine]

Certainly, the expression

Could you please open the door?

contains two hedging devices, and

Could you please just open the door?

three.